# SQL Server Rolling date over

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to update my end date column using the below:

```
update MyTable set EndDate = '2013-07-31 23:59:59.999' where Id = 40
```

The result I am seeing on my table is rolling over to the next day so my column is actually showing as:

```
2013-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

If I take off the milliseconds it leaves it as it but any reason why this is rolling over?

Comment: Is the datatype of the `EndDate` column `DateTime`? If so, this explains the problem. `Datetime` has a precision of 1 tick (3ms), so 999ms is rounded up to 1s. The last "tick" of the seconds is 997ms.

Comment: Why not use LastDate and store that date at midnight, and any clauses that make sure a value happens before that date at 23:59:59.997 use <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, LastDate)? Trying to find the last moment in a day is problematic due to the different precisions of the various date/time types. 23:59:59.999 is not even the last possible moment in the day if you switch to datetime2(7). https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: Using an inclusive start datetime and *exclusive* end datetime is almost always a better way to model intervals (this may be what Aaron's trying to say also).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datetime column's precision is not 1 millisecond, but actually 10/3 ms.

Valid entries always end with 0,3 or 7

So `23:59:59.997` is last possible value in any given day. When you tried to insert .999 it rounded up to the nearest valid value, which was midnight - next day.

[DATETIME type info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

THis is very interesting finding. I tested this table tblTest in SQL Sever 2008, with Birthday as datetime2 and DateEntry as datetime that is the same as your EndDate column, datetime2 may be better than datetime to fit your precision:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Birthday] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DateEntry] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO tblTest (Name) VALUES('Spielberg');

UPDATE tblTest SET DateEntry = '2013-07-31 23:59:59.999' WHERE ID=1
```

Shows exactly the same result as yours:

```
2013-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

Now Birthday as datetime2, the precision is satisfying:

```
UPDATE tblTest SET Birthday = '2013-07-31 23:59:59.999' WHERE ID=1
```

SELECT result is:
    2013-07-31 23:59:59.9990000